# Is it OK to inject value directly inside Bean function?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I was wondering how to do dependency injection in the most effective way inside my code.

I have this code:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeName {
    
    @Autowired
    private Other other;

    @Bean
    public void method() {
        other.someMethod();
        // some code    
    }
}
```

Can this code be changed into the following code(`other` will be used only inside this function)?

```
@Configuration
public class SomeName {
    
    @Bean
    public void method(Other other) {
        other.someMethod();
        // some code    
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work. Although a `void` `@Bean` method is a bit strange.

Comment: `void` was just an example.

Comment: Just use constructor based injection.  Your test cases will be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid @Autowired if possible and inject using a constructor or method.
Starting with Java 9 and java modules (project jigsaw) there are some strict rules that make it harder for your framework to change the values of a private field.
What Spring is doing in the first example is essentially that - it breaks encapsulation to change the value of a private value. (There is a way to overcome this with "opens" directive in module-info..)

You are also becoming dependent on the framework you are using and your code becomes harder to test compared to when using a simple setter.

You are also not explicitly declaring that your class depends on another class since I can easily instantiate it and "Other" will be null.

Some resources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-scanning-autodetection (search for jigsaw)
- https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/

PS: You are probably missing @Configuration on your class

Comment: I agree that there are some pitfalls in my class, but that class is only an illustrative example.

Comment: Can I get you to come re-educate/detox the auto-wire-or-d3ath "devs" at my company?  :) :)

Comment: @granadaCoder one of the hardest part of informatics is actually communicating with your team members. Try to make them do more tests and show them how it is easier to create stubs with constructor / setter injection.

Comment: ha ha.  I have wiki's dedicated to constructor-injection. and links to Mark Seeman.  https://www.google.com/search?q=mark+seeman+%22constructor+injection%22&oq=mark+seeman   But .. some people are married.     The other thing (kissing cousin) is they love to #overMock, which relies on magic-string matching on the name of the @autowire property.  Constant code review comments "inject the dependency in the constructor, do not rely on mock-string-matchign-voodoo.  #goodTImes